# C counterpart to C++ find_first_not_of?

Tags: c, string

Is there a C function which can do the equivalent of find_first_not_of, receiving a string to search and a set of characters and returning the first character in the string that's not of the set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `strspn` function will get you most of the way there. (You just have to massage the return value a bit.)